# wxPython multiple draw functions

Tags: wxpython

I'm new to wxPython. I have two functions that produce different graphical views (simplified in this example as DrawRect1 and DrawRect2). I want to use a menu to switch between these two views.

Most examples I have seen bind EVT_PAINT to a single function called OnPaint, but I don't understand how to define multiple draw functions that can be linked to menu options.

In the code below, I get the desired rectangle drawn, but the background colour is not displayed and I get no error.

I am using ClientDC rather than PaintDC, as I understood this is how different functions can draw to the screen, rather than a single function with EVT_PAINT bound to it.

Is my approach in the code wrong? Or is this just an issue with refreshing the display? I am trying to clear the panel (by recreating it) and then drawing on it (which isn't working since the background colour is not displayed).

```
import wx


class Mywin(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(Mywin, self).__init__(parent, title=title, size=(500, 300))

        self.InitUI()

    def InitUI(self):

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.panel.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour('RED'))


        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)

        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        RectangleButton = wx.Menu()

        Item1 = RectangleButton.Append(wx.ID_ANY, 'Rectangle 1')
        Item2 = RectangleButton.Append(wx.ID_ANY, 'Rectangle 2')

        menuBar.Append(RectangleButton, 'Rectangles')

        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.DrawRect1, Item1)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.DrawRect2, Item2)


    def DrawRect1(self, e):
        self.panel.Destroy()
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, size=self.GetClientSize())
        self.dc = wx.ClientDC(self.panel)
        self.panel.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour('BLUE'))
        self.dc.DrawRectangle(10, 10, 100, 100)

    def DrawRect2(self, e):
        self.panel.Destroy()
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, size=self.GetClientSize())
        self.dc = wx.ClientDC(self.panel)
        self.panel.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour('GREEN'))
        self.dc.DrawRectangle(20, 20, 50, 50)


myApp = wx.App()
Mywin(None,'Drawing demo')
myApp.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `wx.ClientDC` is the right thing to do here since you want to draw from a menu command and not from a `wx.Paint` event.

I guess there is no need to destroy/create the panel everytime you draw so I remove this part from the code.

The other two things to note are:

1.- you need to select a color for the Brush of the `wx.CLientDC` because by default the Brush color will be the same as the panel which results in an invisible rectangle. This is done with the line: `self.dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush(wx.Colour('white')))`

2.- I added a `self.Refresh()` `self.Update()` call before drawing the rectangle to force the change in the panel color and then I draw with the `wx.ClientDC` object. If you place the `self.Refresh()` `self.Update()` at the end of the method then the rectangle disappears.

Here is the code:

```
import wx


class Mywin(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(Mywin, self).__init__(parent, title=title, size=(500, 300))

        self.InitUI()

    def InitUI(self):

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.panel.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour('RED'))


        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)

        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        RectangleButton = wx.Menu()

        Item1 = RectangleButton.Append(wx.ID_ANY, 'Rectangle 1')
        Item2 = RectangleButton.Append(wx.ID_ANY, 'Rectangle 2')

        menuBar.Append(RectangleButton, 'Rectangles')

        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.DrawRect1, Item1)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.DrawRect2, Item2)


    def DrawRect1(self, e):
        self.panel.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour('BLUE'))
        self.Refresh()
        self.Update()
        self.dc = wx.ClientDC(self.panel)
        self.dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush(wx.Colour('white')))
        self.dc.DrawRectangle(10, 10, 100, 100)

    def DrawRect2(self, e):
        self.panel.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour('GREEN'))
        self.Refresh()
        self.Update()        
        self.dc = wx.ClientDC(self.panel)
        self.dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush(wx.Colour('white')))
        self.dc.DrawRectangle(20, 20, 50, 50)

myApp = wx.App()
Mywin(None,'Drawing demo')
myApp.MainLoop()
```